# Dangers of modifying a manufacturer firmware

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, stock-rom, rom-update

I have a device that uses UBIFS instead of YAFFS, and the system partition is truly read-only. As a result, I can only modify the system partition by completely reflashing it. My device is also not fastboot-friendly, so the only way I can flash it is to modify the manufacturer firmware.

Naturally, I would like to root it this way.

If I modify the manufacturer firmware, **test it in an avd**, and it **WORKS**, and then flash it to my device using stock recovery, what are the risks/chances that something will go wrong?

Comment: Possible signature or checksum verification -> won't boot. This is something that immediately comes to mind.

Comment: Won't boot or won't flash?

Comment: And would I be able to recover with recovery?

Comment: It's just my speculation, I don't know for sure...

Comment: @AndyYan If I'm not mistaking, stock recovery doesn't accept flashing anything that's not signed by the manufacturer.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Right. I want to spoof it.

Comment: If you can then you basically just got the key to every custom ROM's first problem - having to use a custom recovery to flash it. It ain't gonna be as easy as you think...

Comment: @AndyYan I didn't say it would be easy. I can definitely spoof their checksum, but I might have to ask them nicely for their signing key. Unfortunately, they don't speak much English and always send me back the exact same "fix" no matter what I say in the email. ;-)

Comment: @NonnyMoose they won't ever hand out their signing key. If they did, and it gets known, noone will buy from them anymore. Too risky.

Comment: @Izzy I was joking. ;-)

Comment: OK then :) I was not, just for the benefit of other users :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The risks involved by reflashing a firmware are :
In case something went wrong during the flashing process (You should have to be very careful while it is flashing tho), The phone will be PERMANENTLY RENDERED unbootable, or you might PREMANENTLY brick your phone.
I strongly suggest you to not to try to do anything above if your device has a warranty from it's manufacturer, otherwise, You may confirm trying to attempt that.

Comment: yeah that should be common sense, but worth mention as many people do stupid things without actually knowing these days ;) anyway, consider answering more recent questions

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot that this existed. Good answer to a bad question.

Comment: Why would it be so? If he only flashes the system partition, he still could use the recovery to unbrick.